# Are you allowed to copy a pointer and call delete on the copy?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, delete-operator

If I copy a pointer and then ask for the pointed to allocation to be deleted, is it valid C++, or is it undefined behavior?

```
char* orig = new char[100];
char* copy = orig;
delete[] copy;
```

Comment: You now have a second pointer to the same deleted array.  That's totally fine, unless you try to use it.

Comment: It's legal, but fairly useless.

Comment: Do not forget to: `orig = NULL; copy = NULL;` after the delete

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's perfectly valid. You are deallocating the array that you allocated on the first line.

Note that copying the pointer doesn't copy the allocated array. So you allocate one array and then you deallocate one array, leaving you with no arrays remaining.

Answer (score 0):

when you delete the 2nd pointer it will delete the allocated array but the first pointer is pointing towards the same memory location therefore it will become the dangling pointer.

Answer (score -1):

but don't forget that orig points to the same memory, so when you delete[] copy the orig pointer becomes unusable as well.... oh sorry Joseph has already said this.